# Vertical ViewPager or Parallax scrolling - android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, vertical-scrolling, vertical-scroll

I am trying to implement similar home Activity like AliExpress android app. I am confused if it was implemented using a vertical ViewPager or Parallax scrolling.

To the best of my knowledge, android only support Horizontal ViewPager swiping left to right. But AliExpress layout looks like a smooth Vertical ViewPager scrolling, with TAB and a horizontal ViewPager at the bottom showing different product categories.

I have tried using the CollapsingToolbarLayout but it was not possible. 
How can I achieve similar Vertical ViewPager?

I am still a beginner android developer. I appreciate any help that points me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found a walk around this by using 'com.github.castorflex.verticalviewpager:library:19.0.1' to create a vertical ViewPager with two pages and then use recycler view on both pages to display content.

Credit to https://github.com/castorflex for the vertical ViewPager library.